# Colorbox parent.$.fn.colorbox.close Can't execute code from a freed script

Tags: jquery, vb.net, internet-explorer, colorbox

I have some logic that works fine, and checks if any inputs have been modified before closing the colorbox.

The colorbox is closed using the parent.$.fn.colorbox.close function. After posting back to the server, this no longer works in Internet Explorer (9, but I'm guessing 7 & 8 would be the same.), the error I am getting is "Can't execute code from a freed script".

I believe this is because IE assumes the parent.window is now disposed? Is there anyway to force the colorbox frame to close?

Works fine in both Chrome and Firefox.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried window.parent.$.fn.colorbox.close() instead?

Comment: No but I shall! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I included some IE-only code that close the colourbox in a different way!